# Slight modifications to bootstrap css overridden on Heroku deployment

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, mean.io

I'm making a simple change to the width of a container. Instead of

```
.container {
    width: 1170px;
}
```

I have

```
.container {
    width: 1350px;
}
```

I've changed it literally everywhere in my repo but it never makes it to production. I'm assuming Heroku just pulls down the standard Bootstrap.css and overrides mine.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Check exactly where you have made changes, on which file and make sure the same file goes to production. Also from browser console make sure that the change is in same line as in production...

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I've definitely double and triple checked, it just looks like during the build process it runs a bower install of boostrap and blows away any changes I make.

Comment: So again it installs `bootstrap`? How you are referring the `bootstrap.css`? through CDN? or from local?

Comment: I am using a local reference but I am using a MEAN stack via mean.io, it might have some other way of referencing it that I am currently unaware of.

Comment: Ok then you have one option left.. keep this `.container{width:1350px !important}` in some other CSS file..

Comment: Seems like that did the trick. Thank you very much

Comment: But let me tell you one important thing.. That destroys the **`specificity`** rule of the `CSS`..  **[`Know more about it here`](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**